# How to include assest using PHP

Tags: php, html, include

Let say, i have a file `product/vps.php` and i want to include it in root folder `index.php`. i can simply use include "product/vps.php"; in `index.php` to include content from `product/vps.php`.

But the problem is when i load index.php the page is broken because `product/vps.php` have lot of `CSS`, `Image` and `Javascript` file from `product/assest/xx`.

How can i write a include in PHP which call content and and also include the sub-content of content file.

Edited :

It possible with defining the root folder with help of `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` or **DIR** or  include_once(ROOT .'product/vps.php');

Comment: `have lot of CSS, Image and Javascript file from product/assest/xx`...ok but _why_ is it broken? Does vps.php have relative links to those assets, which assume they're in the same folder? If so, correct them. This is nothing to do with PHP, it's about HTML because any `<link` or `<script`  tags with URLs in them are interpreted by the browser, relative to the current URL which is showing in the browser's address bar. PHP doesn't touch them. Show us relevant bits of your vps.php code, if you're stuck.

Comment: N.B. If you're including vps.php in another script, then you shouldn't also be trying to have it set up to be loaded independently as well, that's a design flaw, and you would need to think about breaking your code down in a more modular way.

Comment: Show us at least a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code please

Comment: @ADyson it broken because when root folder call the content from other folder and it have linked CSS. the path easily mismatch. in root it will try to call css from `root/asset/xx` instead of the real file in `root/product/assest/xx`

Comment: In that case you need to fix the links then and prepend product/ to them.

Comment: @ADyson what you mean fixing link? you mean to say adding domain name like `example.com/product/assest/img/banner.jpg` instead of `product/assest/img/banner.jpg`

Comment: If the link is already `product/assest/img/banner.jpg` then it should work already, according to what you explained. The error you're mentioning would be the consequence of the link in the page being only `asset/img/banner.jpg`. As I said earlier though, please [edit] the question to provide some actual code samples from vps.php so we can be 100% clear on what we are dealing with, instead of seeing isolated information in the comments, out of context.

Comment: @ADyson sorry it `assest/img/banner.jpg` instead vps.php. Yes index.php in root

Comment: So try with `product/assest/img/banner.jpg` instead, then. The URL in the link must be relative to the URL of the page where the asset is going to be displayed - so it must be relative to index.php, in this case.

Comment: @ADyson then it will get broken at `example.com/product/vps.php`. it not possible to keep both not broken?

Comment: No it's not really possible to keep both easily. As I said above, it smells like a design flaw - why do you want to have the page as a separate and also part of another page? If vps.php has full html, body, head tags etc,  to be able to display on its own, then technically that will produce an invalid HTML doc when fully included into index.php which presumably already has some. Or maybe it doesn't...it's unclear, the scheme you're going for sounds strange and unorthodox. Maybe have a rethink of your design approach.